# ElasticSearch log sorting: GNU sort: how to reverse order if timestamp is the same

Tags: bash, sorting, elasticsearch

I copied some logs from ElasticSearch, which are like:

> YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS [class]-thread-message

I observed some log lines order are incorrect when I do `sort -k 1,2`, I know it's ES's problem that when timestamp are the same, the later logs comes before the early logs. I think by default, `sort` will do nothing to the already sorted lines. I think it's stable(any existing order is not changed).

How could I reverse it with GNU sort, i.e., only reverse sort when sort finds the column has the same value? Or any other utils available in Ubuntu 18.

---

Will delete the question as I realized this is impossible.

The original logs from ES have skewed order **only sometimes** when timestamps are exactly the same, and logs are from the same threads.

I have class A, B, C and the logs comes in the order of A->B->C, but the logs from ES are like:

```
2023-09-26 08:12:04,699 DEBUG [ClassA]-{Camel (camel-1) thread #95516 - Split}-doing things
2023-09-26 08:12:04,699 DEBUG [ClassB]-{Camel (camel-1) thread #95516 - Split}-other things in B
2023-09-26 08:12:04,699 DEBUG [ClassC]-{Camel (camel-1) thread #95516 - Split}-last thing in C
2023-09-26 08:12:04,699 DEBUG [ClassA]-{Camel (camel-1) thread #95516 - Split}-something in A but after line 1
```

So it's not always strictly reversed, because line 1 to line 3 are fine, but line 4 should be put before line 2.

I will delete the question later as this is impossible. Seems logs in ES are sorted randomly by timestamp, not strictly following the real order. I need the real order.

Comment: Your question is not 100% clear. Please provide example inputs, corresponding outputs of `sort -k 1,2`, and your expected output. Meanwhile, if your `sort` is GNU `sort`, try maybe its `-s` (stable) option.

Comment: `sort` is not "stable" by default, it uses last-ditch alphabetic sorting when it hits duplicate sort keys. That's why GNU (and apparently BSD now) have `-s` for when you want stable sort. If you're sorting on the timestamps, and 2 lines have duplicate timestamps, what does "later" and "earlier" mean in "later logs comes before the early logs" for lines that have the same timestamp?

Comment: It would useful if you could build a few lines of log to illustrate your point.

Comment: Checking the log again, I realized that the logs from ElasticSearch still have skewed time order, sometimes with 4 lines logs from the same thread on the same split of seconds. I know the order because by chance this application is done in a streamline fashion, meaning the logs from class A is always before class B, but I see sometimes ES logs have correct order of A, B, sometimes it's B, A on the same split of second. So I guess it's not always reversed, and there's no way to sort it with automation. Will delete OP later as I have voted to close it once

Comment: If you do a simple `sort` without `-k 1,2`, is that what you wanted ?

Comment: neither. without sort it is like the original log, wrong order.

Comment: That's not odd. https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/10005 that's a long existing issue and they seem to solve it in latest version https://www.elastic.co/blog/journey-support-nanosecond-timestamps-elasticsearch which we are not using in production.